# How to put a shortcut to a .bat file on the taskbar

Tags: taskbar, start

I'm trying to make a shortcut on my taskbar for phoenixminer. It's already configured and everything, and It works fine if I have it in a folder anywhere else on my computer. I've had it working before, but I can't remember how I did it and now it's driving me crazy.

Comment: Please avoid using capitals if not needed - this gives the impression that you're shouting.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about Windows 10/11, you can create a new toolbar by right mouse clicking on an empty space on the taskbar:

[image]

'New toolbar...' lets you define one, by pointing towards a folder which contains the shortcuts:

[image]

If you have more than can fit on its taskbar section (also definable), you can drag the shortcuts inside there to change their order.

Comment: Toolbars no longer seem to exist in the Windows 11 taskbar, so this only works for Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Create a shortcut and put something like this as destiny:

"%windir%\system32\cmd.exe" /c "PathtoBat.bat"

Then drag and drop the shortcut to the taskbar.